# Force SwiftUI view to overflow in trailing direction instead of expanding in both directions

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view in an `HStack` that will be wider than it's parent.  When this happens, the `HStack` expands in both `leading` and `trailing` directions, despite being put in a `VStack` with `alignment` set to `.leading` (which I had hoped would anchor the `leading` edge).

Consider the following simplified Playground code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct TestView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 20)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }.frame(height: 40)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                }
                .frame(height: 40)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                }
                .frame(height: 40)
            }
            .border(Color.red)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView())
```

In the above example, everything fits within the view and behaves as expected:
[image: Correctly-behaving view]

However, change the last green `Rectangle` to a `width` of `500` instead of `200`, and the following happens:
[image]

You can see that the orange leading `Rectangle` has disappeared, pushed off to the left.  Similarly, the yellow `Rectangle` at the end has been pushed to the right.

What I would like to have happen is have the orange `Rectangle` visible, meaning that all 3 `HStack`s would have the same `x` origin (0).  So, the result would be seeing the orange Rectangle on the left, the green visible, but spilling over to the right, and the yellow invisible, since it would be pushed off the screen.

I assume this may have to do with using `clipped()` or `fixedSize` but I haven't been able to find a working solution yet.

Comment: So if I understand u correctly, you what all 3 Rec be always visible regardless of the size of them, the green Rec could have 200 or 500 or 1000, you want see them always?

Comment: No -- with the green Rectangle at a width of 500, the orange should be visible on the left, the green will be partially visible and spill off to the right and the yellow will be off the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution (no workarounds or other views required) is to set the `alignment` in the frame modifier of the outer `VStack` to `.leading` like this:

```
struct TestView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 20)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }.frame(height: 40)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                }
                .frame(height: 40)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 500)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                }
                .frame(height: 40)
            }
            .border(Color.red)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400, alignment: .leading)       //<= here
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a clever solution!  However, as you admitted, it's somewhat hacky, and has side effects, like the fact that `disabled` will cascade to the children.  So, I wouldn't be able to have interactive elements inside.  You said you might have other ideas?

Comment: @jn_pdx updated my answer with another solution. Let me know whether that fits your use case. Sometimes GeometryReaders do behave very badly in ScrollViews and dynamically sized views. So maybe I can find another solutions which is only based on basic views like V/HStacks and paddings.

Comment: Your latest solution fails with SIGABRT in a Playground (Xcode 12.1)

Comment: @jn_pdx well I only tested it in a full Xcode (12.1 & 12.2b4) project. Are you required to run it in Playground? Haha I found a solution!! Give me one moment to update my answer

Comment: No, not required to, but one thing I've learned with SwiftUI is that if it crashes one place (like a Playground) it might crash in another (ie Catalyst, or a certain version of iOS).  Just saw your updated solution.  That's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct TestView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 20)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }.frame(height: 40)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                }
                .frame(height: 40)
                
                HStack {
  
                    GeometryReader{_ in
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .frame(width: 10)
                            .offset(x: 0)
                       
                        
                     
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .frame(width: 500)
                            .offset(x: 10)
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            .frame(width: 10)
                            .offset(x: 510)
                    }
                    
                    

                }
                .frame(height: 40)
            }
            .border(Color.red)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool.  Any way to do it if you didn't know the sizes of the rectangles? If they were dynamically sized, you wouldn't be able to set the offset for each element, right?

Comment: That is right, SwiftUI use apple's engineers pre set codes for our renders like inside Hstack or Vstack, If you are not satisfied with them you can use your custom design with  Geometry Topic, this is very advanced and tricky tools, you have to be sure how to use and handel it, otherwise use just HStack or Vstack . .

Comment: Okay.  Going to wait to see if anyone comes up with something that can handle dynamically-sized views, but if not, I think you've got it

Comment: I think you did not understood Geometry, Geometry does not handle dynamically-sized views, You have to tell everything to it, the guy who do that is HStack or VStack, When you are working with Geometry, you have to calculate those thing yourself, It Means You HAVE to write a render logic for that

Comment: I absolutely understand that -- I use GeometryReader often.  I'm just not convinced that there isn't a solution out there a la `fixedSize` (really, the opposite of that) or `clipped` or an alignment setting that covers this case -- for example, there's an answer below doing it using a `ScrollView`.

Comment: fixedSize is used when SwiftUI can expand or un-fixed views! with telling SwiftUI fixedSize, we are telling do not change on this view even is possible from parent views.

Comment: Yes, exactly -- that's why I said "really, the opposite of that"